# La mejor manera de encontrar elementos repetidos en un HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Hice este pequeño programa en NetBeans que utiliza dos HashMap, la idea es que compare los datos dentro de la tabla 1 e imprima los datos en la tabla 2, pero indicando cuantas veces se repiten los datos de la tabla 1, ahora mi pregunta es, hay una mejor forma de hacer esto? (buscar cuáles datos se repiten e imprimir el número de veces que se repitieron) me gustaría saber por cuestiones de performance, cualquier sugerencia o ayuda es bienvenida

```
package actividad.pkg6;

import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class Inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    HashMap<Integer, String> tablaUno = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> tablaDos = new HashMap<>();
    
    private void fillTabla()
    {
        tablaUno.put(1, "Manuel");
        tablaUno.put(2, "Jose");
        tablaUno.put(3, "Arturo");
        tablaUno.put(4, "Manuel");
        tablaUno.put(5, "Alex");
        tablaUno.put(6, "Manuel");
        tablaUno.put(7, "Jose");
        tablaUnoField.setText(tablaUno.toString());
    }
    
    private void contar()
    {
        String element = "";
        String elementTwo = "";
        
        //Iterator iterator = tablaUno.keySet().iterator();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : tablaUno.entrySet()) 
        {
            int count = 0;
            element = entry.getValue();
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry1 : tablaUno.entrySet())
            {                
                elementTwo = entry1.getValue();
                if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(elementTwo))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(!tablaDos.containsKey(element))
            {
                tablaDos.put(element, count);
            }            
        }
    }
    
    private void mostrar()
    {
        tablaDosField.setText(tablaDos.toString());
    }

public Inicio()
    {
        initComponents();
        fillTabla();
    }


private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        contar();
        mostrar();
    }
```

Comment: Comparas cada elemento con todos los demás? Eso es O(n^2) :/
Podrías recorrer el map una sola vez, buscando en tabla dos o, en su defecto, incrementando en 1 el value para ese key.

Comment: Ojo: NetBeans no es un lenguaje. Es un IDE en el que puedes usar distintos lenguajes de desarrollo. En este caso programas usando Java.  pero NetBeans admite usar C, C++, Php entre otros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void contar()
    {
        String element = "";
        String elementTwo = "";
        
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : tablaUno.entrySet()) 
        {
            int count = 0;
            element = entry.getValue();
            
            // extraer la cantidad de veces que existe la clave
            // si no existe la clave se retorna 0 por defecto
            int cuenta = tablaDos.getOrDefault(element,0);
            // incrementar la cuenta
            cuenta++;
            // actualizar la cuenta para esa clave
            tablaDos.put(element,cuenta);
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Con *streams*, puedes usar *Collectors.groupingBy*. De hecho, ignoras que es un mapa y solo usas los valores, igual que si fuera una lista o cualquier otro *Collection*

```
tablaUno.values().stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
       Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
```

Comment: La verdad soy algo nuevo y nunca había utilizado streams o Collector, podrías indicarme cómo hago para imprimir los datos usando eso? Debo de guardar los resultados de lo identificado dentro de alguna variable o cómo imprimo el resultado? Gracias por la ayuda por cierto

Comment: @LuisFerCastilloE dado que tu consulta es con el interés de obtener el mejor rendimiento debo decirte que una solución con streams, aunque es un código más compacto y limpio ( las ventajas de los streams ) puede ser hasta el doble de lenta que otras soluciones.

Comment: @Lobos Gracias por la aclaración, de cualquier forma pienso recurrir a la solución que me habías proporcionado, pero como los streams son temas que desconozco, me interesaba saber cómo aplicarían para mi programa